# Using json encoded data from ajax post to populate radio buttons

Tags: jquery

I need to populate some radio buttons to select a shipping method and price with data depending on which country their order will be shipped to. I am doing this with an AJAX call.

```
$('#ShippingCountry').change(function() { // A dropdown list of countries

    var SelC = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
    type : 'POST', 
    url : 'formprocess.php', 
    data: {Country: SelC},
    dataType : 'json',
    encode : true
    }).done(function(data) {

      //console.log(data.msg); // data.msg is the only thing returned
      // Here I need to construct a list of radio boxes...

    });

});
```

The only thing that is returned is `data.msg`. It is populated like:

```
[
{"ID":"9","Name":"Zone 1 Standard","Charge":"23.00"},
{"ID":"11","Name":"Zone 1 FedEx","Charge":"37.00"},
{"ID":"10","Name":"Zone 1 Express","Charge":"44.50"}
]
```

I need to take this data and make radio buttons for each returned item like:

```
<label class="uit-option gblock">
    <input type="radio" name="ShippingMethod" value="9">
    <span class="radio-option"></span>
    Zone 1 Standard $23.00
</label>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `encode` isn't a jQuery `$.ajax` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just map the data to an array of elements. Shouldn't be too hard

```
var radios = data.msg.map(function(datum) {
    var label = $('<label>').addClass('ui-option gblock').text(datum.Name + ' $' + datum.Charge),
        input = $('<input>').attr({
            type: 'radio',
            name: 'ShippingMethod',
            value: datum.ID
        }),
        span = $('<span>').addClass('radio-option');

    return label.prepend(input, span);
});
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/txb0rbh9/)</kbd>

Comment: This is fine, but it only returns the first item on the array- not all 3.

Comment: @JROB did you even look at the example. It most definitely returns all three